# Creating holes reverts beveled edges

Tags: bevel, boolean-modifier

[image]I am currently having a somewhat similar issue.. I have created a cube that has beveled edges however when I create holes for the intent for screw holes near the corners then use boolean it then creates the holes that I intended but forces the beveled edges to revert back to 90 degree angles. How can I resolve this issue to keep the beveled edges after created the circular holes?

Comment: i would strongly recommend adding pictures of what you have and what you want to have to make it clearer what you want. 1000 words cannot describe a picture better than a picture itself.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the modifier setups, too? It might be easier to identify the problem when we see what your settings are instead of just showing the result. For example: how is the _Bevel_ modifier set up, since there seem to be different beveling on corner and top edges? And the order of the modifiers could be important as well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have bevel modifier and boolean operation creates geometry that would leave bevel operation with overlapping geometry. Bevel modifier automatically clamps overlap. You could disable Clamp Overlap feature in it, but then you will have messy overlapping geometry somewhere that you will need to deal with. This is one of the reasons modellers usually dislike boolean operations ant try to avoid them if possible. Not a big deal, you will just need to deal with the messy geometry before the modifier, or once it's applied if you choose to disable Clamp Overlap.

[image]

You can also move Boolean modifier down so it is after bevel if you are OK with the new holes not having the bevel.

[image]

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you so much for your input and description. I wasn't aware that it was being hidden. When I saw that the bevel went away and so did the option I thought that the only way to getting it back was to try and bevel it once again which sadly resulting in nothing. There is so much about this program for me to learn its unreal lol now will this same method that your doing apply for holes that are passthrough? So meaning that the hole generated will go completely through the project?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Boolean operation depends on the object you use for it. Whatever geometry or type of boolean you use with other modifiers the modifiers will work one after another - top to bottom. Keep in mind that most of the time boolean operations leave messy geometry and that is the real issue here that you should be worrying about.